# how to set a value on mouseenter and replace text in a different div jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, sass, mouseevent

i can't highlight only the tag with the value of mouseenter... I've found each tag in the other div, but all spans are highlighted and all text is blurred. I would understand how to extract only the tag i want on mouseenter and blurred all others.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    //FOCUS SUR LE TAG EN SURVOL
    //CHANGEMENT DE L'OPACITY SUR LES AUTRES
    var leContenu;
    var repl;
    $('.chip').on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
        if (e.type === 'mouseenter'){
            $(this).siblings(".chip").not(".noselect").stop(true, true).animate({'opacity': '0.7'}, 'fast');
            //alert ($(this).text());
            leContenu = $(this).text().trim();
            //alert ($(this).text().trim());
            /*
            if($('.varTag').find('.tagged').length > 0){
                $('.tagged').addClass('highlight');
                $('.varTag').find('.collapsible-body > p').not(".tagged").stop(true, true).animate({'opacity': '0.7'}, 'fast');
                $('.tagged').html().replace(leContenu, "<span class='highlight'>" + leContenu + "</span>");
            }
            */
            if($('.varTag').find('.tagged').length > 0){
                //$('.varTag').find('.tagged').css("color", "$color-bleu").css("font-weight", "bold");
                $('.varTag').find('.collapsible-body > p').not(".tagged").stop(true, true).animate({'opacity': '0.7'}, 'fast');
                //alert ($('.varTag').find('.tagged', leContenu).text());
                $('.varTag').html().replace(leContenu, "<span class='tagged highlight'>"+ leContenu +"</span>");
            }
            else {
                leContenu = $(this).text().trim();

                var rgxp = new RegExp("\\b" + leContenu + "\\b");
                repl = '<span class="highlight">' + leContenu + '</span>';

                $('.Tcard').html($('.Tcard').html().replace(rgxp, repl));
            }
        }
        else {
            //alert ($(this).siblings(".chip").length);
            $(this).siblings(".chip").stop(true, true).animate({'opacity': '1'}, 'fast');
            $('.Tcard').find('.tagged').css("font-weight", "400");
            $('.varTag').find('.collapsible-body > p').stop(true, true).animate({'opacity': '1'}, 'fast');
        }
    });
});
```

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yggcedg8/4/)

How to set or replace only one correspondance?

Comment: Have a look at this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/o_pe95/f4eup6o8/)

Comment: @therealbischero Thank you for your fiddle, your way is much simple and i like it ! thanks again, but there still a question : when i set              

        $('.collapsible-body > p').not('span').stop().animate({
             opacity: '0.5'
         });
i can't reveal only the tag i hover in the text, all p is blurred and i don't find any function to make an exception for it like .not() ... How to set the opacity on the whole text except tags on hover please? That's a big deal

Comment: I'm sorry but I think that's not possible to do.. if you animate a parent element (specially in this type of animation), all the children elements inherits that style.